# What are some good tactics for Khet 2.0?

Tags: khet

I recently bought Khet 2.0 and I've played it a couple of times (we used the "Classic" starting position both times). I didn't really feel like I knew what I was doing as regards tactics / strategy, mostly I seemed to be waiting for my opponent to make a mistake.

What tactics or strategy can I use to help me win?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I feel there really two things that need to focus on in Khet:

- The first is overall board position. You want to create a situation where you have multiple pieces capable of attacking at any given moment, but haven't actually lined up the shot on the main pharaoh. For example, keeping two mirrors positioned on opposite sides of a target, so that when you're able to move an intermediate piece, you have a better chance at an opportunity.
- The other thing I really look at is misdirection. Playing in such a way that an opponent can't determine what direction an attack is coming from is perhaps the easiest approach to this strategy, such as mixing your moves between defense, attack and a few "nonsense" moves (moving pieces that aren't part of your actually strategy in vaguely threatening positions).

There are a few articles on BoardGameGeek regarding this topic as well:

- [Beginning, Middle and Endame Thoughts](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/161000/beginning-middle-and-endgame-thoughts)
- [Opening Moves for Classic Setup](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/192711/opening-moves-for-the-classic-set-up)

Comment: +1 for multiple attacks.  As in chess, keys to success are often forked attacks or multiple-avenue attacks that force the opponent to choose.  Keep options available.  Misdirection is nice, but note that a "nonsense" move should still accomplish something, or it's an empty threat.

Comment: (Also, in the article on Opening Moves, note that threatening the obelisk was a much stronger opening in Khet 1, as it erodes the opponent's defence.  In 2.0 this isn't the case, so concentrate more on mirrors.  It's a good article though.)